# "Can I write 2 instructions in one sml function like that '?

Tags: list, sml, smlnj

So I want to print a list with all the squares of numbers up to n.(in sml nj)

```
Example 
>printl 3 ;
> [0,1,4,9]
```

The thing is **I have to print them using this function "creat"** that creats a list with those:

```
(*print elements squares up to n*)
fun printl n =
( print(Int.toString(hd (creat n [])));  printl(n-1); );

(*creat a list *)
fun creat n acc = if n<0 then acc
else (creat (n-1) ((n*n)::acc) );
```

As you can see, I tried to call "creat" with [] in order to create the desired list of squares up to n and then I tried to print the head  while recursively calling what's left without it (printl n-1).

**I generate this error** though:
`sml square.sml:2.55 Error: syntax error: replacing  RPAREN with  LET`
So I guess there something wrong with the number of instructions in printl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from the semi-colon after `printl(n-1)` because your
compiler waits for another expression.  Hence, the error message
meaning that he won't accept an `)` here but rather a `let`.  So just
remove that semi-colon.

Note that the semi-colon has two different meanings:

- either to sequence expressions `a ; b ; c`.  So in that context `a ; b ;` is syntactically incorrect ;
- or either to mark the end of a declaration at a top level in order
  to let the compiler know you are done with the current definition (as
  you have done for your two functions).